# Where to add custom column types to filter panel - MUI Datagrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I cannot figure out where to add my custom column type inside of my DataGrid. I tried adding it to the filterPanel inside of the DataGrid, but it didn't seem to work. I can't find anything in the documentation showing WHERE to add the custom column type.

Here is the documentation for creating a column type: [https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/#:~:text=to%20start%20editing-,Custom%20column%20types,-When%20defining%20a](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/#:%7E:text=to%20start%20editing-,Custom%20column%20types,-When%20defining%20a)

Here is my code:

```
export const MultiSelectColumnType: GridColTypeDef = {
  extendType: 'singleSelect',
  filterOperators: getGridSingleSelectOperators().filter(
    (operator) => operator.value === 'is' || operator.value === 'not' || operator.value === 'isAnyOf',
  ),
};
```

Here is my DataGrid:

````
       <DataGridPro
              selectionModel={selectionModel()}
              hideFooterSelectedRowCount
              disableSelectionOnClick
              keepNonExistentRowsSelected
              rows={TableRows}
              columns={TableColumns}
              loading={tableIsLoading}
              rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 500]}
              pagination
              paginationMode="server"
              sortingMode="server"
              filterMode="server"
              filterModel={filterModel}
              onFilterModelChange={(model, details) => {            
                setFilterModel(model)
              }}
              page={currentPagination.page}
              rowCount={totalRows}
              pageSize={currentPagination.page_size}
              onPageChange={(PageNumber, details) => {
                setCurrentPagination({ page: PageNumber, page_size: currentPagination.page_size });
              }}
              onPageSizeChange={(numberOfRows, details) => {
                setCurrentPagination({ page: 0, page_size: numberOfRows });
              }}
              onSortModelChange={(cols, details) => {
                //TODO: [CNG-446] Add multi sorting to server
                setCurrentSorting({
                  sortby: _.get(cols, [0, 'field'], 'id'),
                  direction: _.get(cols, [0, 'sort'], 'desc'),
                });
              }}
              density="compact"
              components={{
                Toolbar: CustomToolBar,
                Footer: CustomFooter,
              }}
              componentsProps={{
                toolbar: {
                  tableData: rows.length,
                  totalData: totalRows,
                  customToolbarButton,
                  tableType, 
                },
                footer: {
                  totalRows: !isAllSelected ? selectedRows.length : totalRows - excludedRows.length,
                },
                filterPanel: {
                  columnTypes: MultiSelectColumnType, // I thought to add it here
                  linkOperators: ['and'] 
                }
              }}
              onCellClick={(data, event, details) => {
              }}
              localeText={{
                toolbarDensity: translate('Density'),
                toolbarDensityCompact: translate('Compact'),
                toolbarDensityStandard: translate('Standard'),
                toolbarDensityComfortable: translate('Comfortable'),
                toolbarExport: translate('Export'),
                toolbarColumns: translate('Columns'),
                toolbarColumnsLabel: 'Select columns',
                columnsPanelTextFieldLabel: translate('Find column'),
                columnsPanelTextFieldPlaceholder: translate('Column title'),
                columnsPanelDragIconLabel: translate('Reorder column'),
                columnsPanelShowAllButton: translate('Show all'),
                columnsPanelHideAllButton: translate('Hide all'),
                noRowsLabel: translate('No rows'),
                MuiTablePagination: {
                  labelRowsPerPage: translate('Rows Per Page:'),
                  labelDisplayedRows: ({ from, to, count }) => (
                    <span id="rtl-label-display-rows-container">
                      <span>&nbsp;{`${from} - ${to}`}&nbsp;</span> <span>{`${translate('Of')} ${count}`}</span>
                    </span>
                  ),
                },
              }}
              autoHeight
              sx={{
                border: 'none',
              }}
            />
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Realized I added it in the wrong place. I needed to add it directly to the dataGrid and not to the filterPanel

```
  columnTypes={{ MultiSelectColumnType }}
```

DataGrid API: [https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#css:~:text=slice%20is%20rendered.-,columnTypes,-object](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#css:%7E:text=slice%20is%20rendered.-,columnTypes,-object)